# TypeError: Cannot read property 'gmail' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

```
let fs = require('fs');
let google = require('googleapis');

getMessage(userId, messageId, callback) {
    let gmail = this.getGmailService();
    var request = google.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
        'userId': userId,
        'id': messageId
    });
    request.execute(callback);
}
```

when I call this method from a spec

```
getMessage('abcd123987@gmail.com', '15934550ay626ud09')
```

it spits out the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'gmail' of undefined
```

any comments/suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the browser with e.g. browserify or are you using nodejs?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 options:
1. You didn't install the googleapis node module.
2. You didn't import it well.
3. You didn't use it well.

Option 1 fix:
Install the googleapis node module:
yarn add googleapis

Option 2 fix:
In the new version of googleapis (V26) I needed to change my import line to the following:
var {google} = require('googleapis');

Option 3 fix:
You are calling it via google.client.gmail, perhaps use just google.gmail